# Does Fuse ESB 4.2 have features(group of bundles) in it?

Tags: osgi, fuseesb, jbossfuse

when i see the avaliable commands on the karaf console.there is no "**features:**" commands. Are their only osgi bundles in 4.2 or did i download sumthing else

@Claszen

thank you for the answer but it did not work. i downloaded the 66.54 mb zip file meant for windows. and on running the servicemix.bat the following error's prop up before the servicemix logo. any help will be appreciated

> Bundle listed in startup.properties
>   configuration not found:
>   org/apache/felix/karaf/deployer/org.apache.felix.karaf.deployer.features/1.4.0-fuse-02-00/org.apache.felix
>   Bundle listed in startup.properties
>   configuration not found:
>   org/apache/felix/karaf/deployer/org.apache.felix.karaf.deployer.blueprint/1.4.0-fuse-02-00/org.apache.feli
>   Bundle listed in startup.properties
>   configuration not found:
>   org/apache/felix/karaf/features/org.apache.felix.karaf.features.management/1.4.0-fuse-02-00/org.apache.fel
>   Bundle listed in startup.properties
>   configuration not found:
>   org/apache/felix/karaf/features/org.apache.felix.karaf.features.command/1.4.0-fuse-02-00/org.apache.felix.
>   Bundle listed in startup.properties
>   configuration not found:
>   org/apache/felix/karaf/admin/org.apache.felix.karaf.admin.management/1.4.0-fuse-02-00/org.apache.felix.kar
>   Bundle listed in startup.properties
>   configuration not found:
>   org/apache/felix/karaf/deployer/org.apache.felix.karaf.deployer.spring/1.4.0-fuse-02-00/org.apache.felix.k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature commands are there. Start typing 'feat' and than press tab

```
karaf@root> features:

features:addUrl        features:install       features:list          features:listUrl       features:refreshUrl
features:removeUrl     features:uninstall
```

EDIT:

Also ensure that you unzipped/untared the archiv properly. The first feature mentioned in your list shoudl be located here (the others analog):

```
apache-servicemix-4.2.0-fuse-02-00\system\org\apache\felix\karaf\deployer\org.apache.felix.karaf.deployer.features\1.4.0-fuse-02-00\org.apache.felix.karaf.deployer.features-1.4.0-fuse-02-00.jar
```

Maybe something went wrong with unpacking the archive.

EDIT:

Also maybe your etc/startup.properties file might be corrupt. In my version no

```
org/apache/felix/karaf/deployer/org.apache.felix.karaf.deployer.features/1.4.0-fuse-02-00/org.apache.felix
```

bundle (the first in your error list) is mentioned but

```
org/apache/felix/karaf/deployer/org.apache.felix.karaf.deployer.features/1.4.0-fuse-02-00/org.apache.felix.karaf.deployer.features-1.4.0-fuse-02-00.jar=30
```

which can be found on the path I mentioned in my first edit.

Comment: thanks for your answer..did not seee the edit parts till now :)...just using the fuse 4.3..everything works fine now.Except for the activeMQ web console..and error's while installling some URL's using features:install..wish there was a comprehensive article on how to setup...the one on the fuse site is very basic